# assign array size with external global variable c++

Tags: c++, global-variables

I have the following simple example code:

1.

```
//param.h
extern int n;
```

2.

```
//param.cpp
int n =10;
```

3.

```
# include <iostream>
# include "param.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double Arr[n];
    return 0;
}
```

It does not compile since I cannot n is not defined.

why, what is the best way to resolve this issue while keeping the same structure?

Comment: Consider `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n` is non-const: you can't declare a static array using `n` as the size. As @NickyC pointed in the comments, the simple solution is to replace array with [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> Arr(n/*, default_value*/);
```

If you want to keep going with arrays, you must either declare `n` as const:

```
// param.h
extern const int n;

// param.cpp
const int n = 10;
```

or declare a dynamic array:

```
double* Arr = new double[n];
...
delete[] Arr;
return 0;
```

or better with a managed pointer:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<double[]> Arr = std::make_unique<double[]>(n);
```

Answer (score 6):

Two things: First of all you need to link with all object files generated from source. The second is that [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not a valid C++ construct.

To solve the first problem you need to make sure you compile both source files. Either together on the command line, or into separate object files that you link together to form the executable.

The second problem can be solved by using the `const` keyword in the declaration and definition to make it a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 4):

The variable n in the declaration

```
double Arr[n];
```

should be a constant known at compile-time.

In param.h, you can declare

```
constexpr int n = 10;
```

and suppress it from param.cpp.

If n is intrinsically a variable, another solution is to keep the files params as you have defined it and to use alloca to allocate your array Arr on the stack.

You can also allocate Arr in the heap with

```
 double* Arr = new double[n];
```

But you should delete it at the end of the function with delete [] Arr;